# Nginx high memory usage duplicate SSL

Tags: nginx, memory-usage

We have an NGINX running with a lot of virtual hosts (~600)
Unfortunately the NGINX workers are each using a large chunk of residential memory (~6GB)

When inspecting the memory (strings) it yields the duplicate meta information you usually find in SSL certs (duplicated up to over 100.000 times). We only use a handful different certs.

I suspected ssl_session_cache could be the culprit. It is set to

> ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

which would nicely add up to our memory usage (10MB*600=6GB)
But according to the docs http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache

> A cache with the same name can be used in several virtual servers.

And increasing that value does apparently have no effect memory usage.

We also heavily rely on lua-resty, but that shouldn't affect how SSL is handled?

Do you know what could be causing this high memory usage?

nginx version: openresty/1.13.6.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were using Openresty mostly for authentication. As we were suspecting Openresty to cause the high memory usage we extracted all lua parts with an `auth_request` Now we have an nginx which proxies back to openresty for authentication.

With the same number of hosts and SSL certificates we now have a much lower memory usage (~150MB per worker instead of 6GB). Also openresty only uses a negligible amount of memory. So there seems to have been some problem with openresty in combination other parts of our configuration.

While this does not exactly answers the original question, it is a useful workaround for us and hopefully anyone else who hits this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this happens because nginx has a separate memory allocated for each virtual server's settings, and that memory area includes a copy of the certificate being used. This implies that even if you have only a few separate certificates, they are being duplicated in memory when they are used in separate virtual servers.

SSL session cache doesn't contain certificate data, it only contains session data for active SSL sessions between clients and the server.